# Nextjs 14 - API response is not defined when switching to client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the existing Nextjs code that implements a simple ReviewsPage, displaying the newest 6 reviews from a Strapi CMS. All works as expected:

**app > reviews > page.jsx**

```
// IMPORTS 

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Reviews',
};

const PAGE_SIZE = 6;

export const ReviewsPage = async ({ searchParams }) => {
  // Extracting page parameter from searchParams
  const parsePageParam = (paramValue) => {
    if (paramValue) {
      const page = parseInt(paramValue);

      if (isFinite(page) && page > 0) {
        return page;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  };

  const page = parsePageParam(searchParams.page);
  const { reviews, pageCount } = await getReviews(PAGE_SIZE, page);

  return (
    <>
      <Heading>Reviews</Heading>
      <div className="flex justify-between pb-3">
        <PaginationBar href="/reviews" page={page} pageCount={pageCount} />
        <Search />
      </div>

      <ul className="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-3">
        {reviews?.map((review, index) => (
          <ReviewCard review={review} index={index} key={review?.slug} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default ReviewsPage;
```

**lib > reviews.js**

```
import 'server-only';

import { marked } from 'marked';
import qs from 'qs';

export const CACHE_TAG_REVIEWS = 'reviews';

const CMS_URL = process.env.CMS_URL;

export const getReviews = async (pageSize, page) => {
  const { data, meta } = await fetchReviews({
    fields: ['slug', 'title', 'subtitle', 'publishedAt'],
    populate: { image: { fields: ['url'] } },
    sort: ['publishedAt:desc'],
    pagination: { pageSize, page },
  });

  return {
    pageCount: meta?.pagination?.pageCount,
    reviews: data?.map(toReview),
  };
};

const fetchReviews = async (parameters) => {
  const url =
    `${CMS_URL}/api/reviews?` +
    qs.stringify(parameters, { encodeValuesOnly: true });

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    next: {
      tags: [CACHE_TAG_REVIEWS],
    },
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`CMS returned ${repsonse.status} for ${url}`);
  }
  return await response.json();
};

const toReview = (item) => {
  const { attributes } = item;
  return {
    slug: attributes?.slug,
    title: attributes?.title,
    subtitle: attributes?.subtitle,
    date: attributes?.publishedAt.slice(0, 'yyyy-mm-dd'.length),
    image: CMS_URL + attributes?.image.data.attributes.url,
  };
};
```

However, I've been trying to extend the current ReviewsPage component to `useState` as I'm going to introduce another child component which will be a client component.

Hence, I add `use client`, and remove the metadata export. Then I remove 'server-only' from review.js but then I continually get the below build error:

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: repsonse is not defined at fetchReviews` - I'm new to Nextjs but cannot understand why this is changing the reponse when its a client component? The following is output when I log `response` in fetchReviews:

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: { settingsObject: {} },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: false,
    requestIncludesCredentials: false,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: null,
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [],
    body: { stream: undefined, source: [Uint8Array], length: 1641 }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(15) {
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'content-security-policy' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'keep-alive' => [Object],
      'referrer-policy' => [Object],
      'strict-transport-security' => [Object],
      'vary' => [Object],
      'x-content-type-options' => [Object],
      'x-dns-prefetch-control' => [Object],
      'x-download-options' => [Object],
      'x-frame-options' => [Object],
      'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies' => [Object],
      'x-powered-by' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct if my assumptions are wrong. You are trying to build reviews page ( paginated ). and you want to use a client component to append the page number to URL ( pagination component ) on button click or something...

A server component ( reviews ) will accept child components ( pagination component to listen for button clicks) as children.

Separate your client component ( use-client ) from the server component. whenever the user changes the page, appends the **page** query param to URL (the new URL would be xxxxx.org/reviews?page=2 and then navigate to newly constructed url

you client component should be like this

```
     "use client"
import { usePathname, useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

   export default function paginationComponent(props){
const pathname = usePathname();
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
     function onPageChange(page: string) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
        if (page) {
          params.delete("page");
          params.set("page",page);
        }
        replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
      }
    return (
     <ClientComponent onClick={onPageChange} />
)


}
```

with this your data fetch happens on server only ( you dont have to change anything ). url based pagination works

**This is what i'm suggesting to turn your reviews server component in to client component - from our discussion**

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Reviews",
};
const PAGE_SIZE = 6;

export default function ReviewsPage() {
  // no async as it is not a server component
  const [reviews, setReviews] = React.useState([]);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = React.useState(0); // change as required
  const parsePageParam = (paramValue: string) => {
    if (paramValue) {
      const page = parseInt(paramValue);

      if (isFinite(page) && page > 0) {
        return page;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  };

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const page = parsePageParam(searchParams.get("page") || "1");

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch reviews
    async function fetchReviews() {
      // fetch reviews
      const { reviews, pageCount } = await getReviews(PAGE_SIZE, page);
      // react batch state updates
      setReviews(reviews);
      setPageCount(pageCount);
    }
    fetchReviews();
  }, [page]);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer. The current pagination behaviour has been implemented correctly and works as expected.

The issue I am facing is when I introduce a <Filters /> component - which displays various radio buttons to the user which will eventually allow filtering of results.

However, without adding that component and just converted ReviewsPage to a client component, response from fetchReviews is always undefined.

Comment: so you want to allow users to apply filter after page has been rendered. thats why you wanted to use useState to store reviews data and apply filters . these filters are on client side but not on data fetching side ( strapi cms ).... understood

if you trying to change reviews component to client - you need to remove async await and use useEffect hook to fetch the data and update the state ( with reviews data ). then it wont give any issue. basically this line  const { reviews, pageCount } = await getReviews(PAGE_SIZE, page); goes in to useEffect with page number as dependency..

Comment: hey - appreciate the attempt, but you reference removing useEffect, no where in my snippet above is that included.

Comment: No what i'm saying is you need to use useEffect. check my main answer... i have edited it to show how can you turn your server component to client component.